# how to know my app can be open in newsstand

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, newsstand-kit, auto-renewing, renewal

In my application ,there are two things coupons and articles. On purchasing coupons all articles are visible to the user otherwise only some articles can be viewed. For purchasing I used in App purchase and the in app product are of two types consumable and auto renewable. So I wanted to know whether my application can be uploaded to be opened in newsStand or not??
please guide
Thanks

Comment: what do you exactly want ? you want to know how to open a apps in NewsStand.

Comment: Actually i want to know my app can be open in newsstand or not with the functionality i explained above

Comment: As per my view no you cant put it on Newsstand.

Comment: @DeepGami i cannot put failing on which criteria??

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/newsstand/

Comment: all those links i checked but i am having in App purchase and auto Renewal subscription thing in my app and also articles are available to user and that is the must condition for an app to be submitted as newsstand for this reason i am confused.